# programming 3 or more buttons at the same screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to program 3 clickable buttons at the some layout.

- The first button to send an email.
- The second button to link to some website.
- The third button to go to some facebook page.

I'm really stuck because I already have a button to go back or to the previous screen. And I already called to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

At the first button on the java file and honestly I don't know how to keep going to make the next three buttons work. I already had read some tutorials about it but I don't get it yet. Maybe my case is so simple but I'm starting by myself to do this. So I will appreciate any help from anybody.

Comment: maybe i didnt post it at the right place,..or with the right tag(s)..so sorry if my posts are annoying to somebody.

Comment: DId you mean to include the `android` tag?

Comment: im really sorry,,. i forgot.. im programming my app in eclipse..

Comment: i meant " maybe i didnt post my question with the right tag"..i posted my question with : tagged button x7198 ..i don't know what it means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" );
        startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
        }
    }); 
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.facebook.com/abc" );
        startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if i have 100 buttons? Is this feasible and optimized way to implement this way? :)

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/email" />

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iconlogoapp" />

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook" />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: those are the 3 buttons from my .xml file ...i just dont know how to make them clickables

Comment: All u have to do change the above code replacing btn1, btn2 & btn2 with button2,button3 & button4 respectively. only in the first 3 line of the code like 

`btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);` . similarly. You dont have to do anything to make them clickable. onClickListeners will be binded to them dynamically.

Comment: @RahmathullahMPulikkal ITS TOTALLY WORKING MAN ,.. YOURE THE MAN !!

just one more question (s) : 

what do i need to put in " Choose an Email client :"  ???

Comment: i  really dont know what to put  in  : " Choose an Email client :"

Comment: Pleasure :) , 
You need not put anything there.
If you run this on emulator, you will hit error message : “No application can perform this action“. This code only work on real device. :)

Comment: @RahmathullahMPulikkal ..its all Good  ,.everything is working so perfectly ,.THANKS ALOT I DO REALLY APPRECIATE IT ,.. ...THIS FORUMIS SO AMAZING with so many nice answers and help ...Great idea & Thanks God for stack overflow.com !!

Comment: ok man,..Thanks ..i already  run it on my device ..its working :) .. FIVE STARS FOR YOU..FOR HELPING PEOPLE !!

Answer (score 2):

The below way is the **Optimized way** of implementing Click listener for View.

You can include `android:onClick="myClickHandler"` inside every button in XML layout.

Now, declare a `myClickHandler()` method inside the Activity class as below:

```
public void myClickHandler(View v)
{
     switch(v.getId()) {
          case R.id.button1:
            // code to execute on button1 click
           break;

          case R.id.button2:
            // code to execute on button1 click
           break;

          case R.id.button3:
            // code to execute on button1 click
           break;

     }      
}
```

Comment: See, this is the optimized way to implement click listener. let me know what are the error you got.

Comment: :i got 2 errors : Syntax error on token "(",;expected  & an error at : void is an invalid type for variable myClickHandler

Comment: @user1586218 it seems minor mistake you made in your code. Check it carefully.